# I can't get daisyui's theme to propagate in a next.js app

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css, daisyui

I am trying to use a theme from "Daisyui" which is a tailwind based css component library https://daisyui.com/. I have a next.js app where the entry point is `pages/_app.tsx`. From looking at examples and reading the website's documentation, it looks like the theme is passed on from the highest component to all of the inwards components.

You add `daisyui` to the `tailwind.config.js` file, Like this:
[image]

I made my `tailwind.config.js` file look like this:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
    //...
    content: ['./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
    plugins: [require("daisyui")],
    daisyui: {
      themes: true
    }
  }
```

`true` means that all the themes are included.

I added the theme "synthwave" to the highest level component of the next.js app which is a div tag wrapping around `Component`:

```
import '../styles/globals.css'
import type { AppProps } from 'next/app'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
  return (
    <div theme-data="synthwave">
  <Component {...pageProps} />
  </div>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```

I also made a postcss.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: ['tailwindcss', 'autoprefixer'],
  };
```

And I imported

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

at the top of globals.css.

This fails because the resulting webpage is just plain white.
[image]

But what's weird is when I change `daisyui: { themes: true }` in `tailwind.config.js` to `daisyui: { themes: ["synthwave"] }`. The webpage IS correctly themed with daisyui's synthwave:
[image]

I'm assuming that this only works because it's overriding ALL styles on every page and I don't want that. I want to be able to declare different themes on any page if I want to. So how do I correctly set the theme for the entire app in a way that I can override it on individual pages if I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link is very helpful https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document. You can make a file called `_document.js` that can update the  and  tags used to render a page. Just like the link says, I created a file called `_document.js` in `pages` that looks like this:
pages/_document.js:

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

export default function Document() {
  return (
    <Html data-theme="synthwave">
      <Head />
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
```

Notice this piece of code `<Html data-theme="synthwave">`. It correctly set `index.tsx` to `daisyui`'s `synthwave` theme.

Answer (score 0):

Experienced the same issue but this worked

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx,mdx}',
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
    },
  },
  daisyui: {
    themes: true,
  },
  plugins: [require("daisyui")],
}
export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en" data-theme={'aqua'}>
      <body className={inter.className}>{children}</body>
    </html>
  )
}
```